# Getting only the first value of a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which provides this result below.
How do I create another function to show only the 1st result instead of all the results?

```
 turn-left
 turn-right
 turn-left
```

The code below shows how I get the result above.

```
function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(steps) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row);  
    row.append($("<td>" + steps.maneuver + "</td>"));
    console.log('Added Table');     
}
```

I have created another function which will get all the results above and place it in the html. However, I only want to get the first result instead of all the results.

```
function getArrows() {
    $('#personDataTable td').each(function(idx, element) { 
        var text = $(element).text();
        $('#Arrows').append(text + ' , ');
        console.log('gotArrows');
    });
}
```

I would want all the results for the 1st function but the 2nd function, i only want the 1st result of the 1st function.

Comment: Don't use each or a loop. `drawRow(data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0]);`

Comment: for the first function, I would like to get all the rewards. for the 2nd function , I would only want the 1st result of all the results from the 1st function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first *td* of first *tr*, you do not need to use loop at all. Simply use `:first` selector like `$('#personDataTable tr:first td:first')`.

```js
function getArrows() {
  var text = $('#personDataTable tr:first td:first').text();
  console.log(text);
  $('#Arrows').append(text + ' , ');
  console.log('gotArrows');
} 
getArrows()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="personDataTable">
  <tr><td>Fisrt</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Second</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Third</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="Arrows"></div>
```

Comment: I fail to see why this was downvoted, it appears to answer the question fine.

Comment: @NickA Most likely someone saw jQuery in the answer and didn't see it as a tag. Didn't check the actual question either, so didn't notice OP using jQuery. Or perhaps it was a matter of _"Don't answer bad questions"_. Or even someone just not liking Mamun. Fact is, everyone can vote and the reasons aren't always clear. If you disagree with it, cancel it out by an upvote :)

Comment: @icecub I'm well aware of the intricacies of voting :), some days it just bemuses me, I guess I need coffee...

Comment: @NickA Ye I know. Perhaps it was because of the lack of any explanation in the answer. I honestly don't think any of the mentioned reasons warant a downvote. They're just not really upvote worthy either. Anyway, coffee.. good idea